# run() And runOnUIThread() method internal difference

Tags: android

Can anyone explain internal mechanism of both this methods. What makes run corresponds only logic not ui and what makes runOnUiThread make UI changes possible.

Answer (score 2):

run() is the interface method a [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) implements

[runOnUiThread(Runnable action)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread) takes a Runnable which implements the run() method and executes it on the MainThread.

Views can only be changed from the MainThread therefore run() executed from every other thread will result in an error

Answer (score -1):

runOnUiThread internally gets the Main or UI Thread and runs the code written inside it on the Main/UI thread.

run method initializes a new thread in the Executor Pool which is randomly assigned to it. Hence you cannot run UI changes code in a run method.

Comment: This isn't correct. `run` does *not* initialize a new `Thread`. It is executed inline from wherever it is called.